# Getting the difference of the cells

Tags: vba, excel

Anyone knows how to get the difference between the two cells with condition. My problem is that if `Column W` contains the value of `FAILED`, then I have to get the difference of `Column P` and `Column Q` and put the difference to `Column Z`. Then I have to do this up until the last row that has a data in `Column W`. I have this code so far:

```
If ws.Range("W3") = "FAILED" Then
    ws.Range("Z3") = ws.Range("P3") - ws.Range("Q3")
Else
    ws.Range("Z3") = ""
End If

ws.Range("Z3").Copy
ws.Range("Z3:Z" & GetLastRow(ws)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: if you want only a difference between 2 columns based on a third one why you don't use excel formula? and after copy that column with vba?

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: `IF` to check for the presence of data, `SUMIFS` to do the math

Comment: @DirkReichel It is not working as expected. It is not doing the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub GetDiff()
Dim Ws As Worksheet, lRw As Long

Set Ws = ActiveSheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Ws
    lRw = .Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range("Z3:Z" & lRw)
        .Formula = "=IF(W3=""Failed"",SUM(P3)-SUM(Q3),0)"
        .Calculate
        DoEvents 'This will let the formula to calculate before converting it to values
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This already works, but I want the value `0` to be just a blank one. Do you have any idea how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Just replace 0 with """" (Four Double Quotes)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this in VBA then you could change your code to:

```
Sub calc()
    Dim ws As Object
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Row = 3
    Do
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Rows(Row)) = 0 Then Exit Do 'exit loop if row is empy
        If ws.Cells(Row, 23).Text = "FAILED" Then
            ws.Cells(Row, 26) = ws.Cells(Row, 16) - ws.Cells(Row, 17)
        Else
            ws.Cells(Row, 26) = ""
        End If
        Row = Row + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Notice I favored numeric references to columns.

But unless you plan to escalate to a more complex case, I would stick with a formula on the Z column:

```
=IF(W1="FAILED",P1-Q1,"")
```

Comment: I'm sorry but if I debug the code, I don't see what is really happening. What if I change it the condition in `Column X` that has the `FAILED` value? and has to get the difference of `Column R` and `Column S` and put the value to `Column AA`? Any help ?Thanks!

Comment: You are probably having a hard time with the `.Cells(RowNumber, ColumnNumber)` syntax. You have to think that column 1 = 'A', column 2 = 'B' ... column 23 = 'W' ... column 26 = 'Z'. So `ws.Cells(Row, 26)` refers to row `Row` and column 'Z'. To change it to column 'AA' you would use `ws.Cells(Row, 27)`  instead.

Comment: If you prefer, you can use `ws.Range("Z" & Row)` instead of `ws.Cells(Row, 26)`.